# List bad blocks and affected files

Tags: linux, filesystems, ntfs, badblocks

I made a full disk image from a 4 to 5 year old laptop HDD.

That HDD was in a laptop that was carried often to places, so, over the years, it has probably experienced physical stresses to some degree.

The HDD still works intact, but Guymager, the program I used, showed how many bad sectors were encountered while capturing that image; specifically, 19 bad sectors.

Which LBA numbers and which files are affected by these 19 bad sectors?

I would first like to create a list of bad LBA's and then I would like to list every file on each of those LBA's in a separate step.

Comment: What kind of filesystem is/was it?  What OS are you using to attempt the recovery?

Comment: @JeffSchaller The target file system is unfortunately NTFS. OS is Linux Mint Mate

Comment: Mate 64-Bit 18.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What works listing blocks on all disks independent from file systems? (low-level). And what works with FAT and NTFS?

The LBA number and bad block detection is total independent of the file system. *Finding files* is completely dependent on the filesystem. Don't expect a single tool to work for all filesystems.

You can use `badblocks` to scan for bad blocks, you can use `smartctl` to get the LBA(s) of reallocated blocks or bad blocks detected by the harddisk firmware, and you can use `fdisk` etc. if you want to calculate between partition-relative numbers (if you did e.g. `badblocks /dev/sda1` and LBAs.

As mentioned in the other answer, you can find the affected files for ext2/ext3/ext3 with `debugfs`.

You can use the [fibmap ioctl](http://smackerelofopinion.blogspot.com/2009/06/fibmap-ioctl-file-system-block-number.html) to find the LBA of the n-th block of a given file for all filesystems, but if you want to find the file for a given LBA, this is probably not practical. There's also `filefrag`, which probably uses this ioctl.

I'm sure there are forensic tools for FAT (and possibly even for NTFS) which find a file for a given block number, but I couldn't name any offhand.

**Edit**

Googling finds [fatcat](https://github.com/Gregwar/fatcat) for forensic analysis of FAT filesystems; it seems with `-L` you can get a file for a specific cluster (which you can calculate from the LBA). I have no experience with this program. Googling more will probably turn up more such programs.

Comment: +1. But *`The LBA number and bad block detection is total independent of the file system. Finding files is completely dependent on the filesystem.`*    | I knew that, so maybe I have asked two questions seperately.

Comment: Can I use LBA lists instead of complete rescans?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you have an LBA list, you don't need to "scan" (`badblocks` etc.)- you already have the list. If you want files for a list of blocks for a non-ext filesystem, you still need tools for that specific filesystem. You can "scan" with fibmap, you can even script the scan to use a list of blocks and only touch each file once, but it's still an impractical way to do. It would help if you'd actually describe your situation (like "the harddisk has a FAT and a NTFS partition"), instead of asking general questions for which there's no definite answer.

Comment: Sorrry, I see. The first thing is finding every dead sector and creating a LBA list, which only needs to do a low-level scan. **Then,** list every file with is laying on that LBA in a **seperate step.**

Comment: Yes. As I already wrote: You can use `smartctl` (internally reallocated sectors) and `badblocks` (currently non-readable sectors) for the first step. But didn't you already get the list from Guymager? I'd also advise not to work directly with the harddisk, but use `ddrescue` etc. to first make a copy of the harddisk (which will also detect bad sectors while doing this).

Comment: Where is that list? Guymager only shows the **number of** bad sectors.

Comment: I have no idea, I've never used Guymager. But if it knows the number of bad sectors, it should also know *which* sectors are bad. Just reporting their number isn't particularly helpful...

Comment: I agree. By the way, how do I find dead sectors from raw and gzipped AFF/EWF images?

Comment: Just added this answer as accepted because it answers the question. I searched for a NTFS equivalent, **but your answer has been quite useful meanwhile.**

Answer (score 7):

Use debugfs on ext2/3/4.
First find the inode based on block:

```
debugfs -D -R "icheck $sda3block4096" /dev/sda3
```

then use this inode number for query for file:

```
debugfs -D -R "ncheck $inode" /dev/sda3
```

Comment: You probably should mention that `debugfs` only works on ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystems.

Comment: @dirkt What works listing blocks on all disks independent from file systems? (low-level). And what works with FAT and NTFS?

Answer (score 2):

#### NTFS, ext3, ext4

If you've copied the data off your fail{ing,ed} drive with `ddrescue`, then use [`ddrutility`](https://sourceforge.net/p/ddrutility/wiki/Home/) which was created for just this purpose.

I successfully got it to list affected NTFS files given a `ddrescue` mapfile in under 20 seconds.

It writes its log file in the current directory.

The linked page mentions support for NTFS, ext3 and ext4.

#### btrfs

btrfs has it's own built-in `scrub` function.