# Generating dead LBA list from gddrescue mapfile/logfile?

Tags: data-recovery, data, data-cd, ddrescue

I ultimately would like to know **which files** in images generated by (g)ddrescue **are affected by damage.**

---

**gddrescue** (command `ddrescue`) is a tool for recovering data from damaged media.

When specifying the `/dev/device` and `output.file`, a *logfile* or *mapfile* can be specified as well, which is highly recommended.

Such a *logfile* or *mapfile* some relevant information for being able to resume the recovery process at any time after interruption, which includes **a list of damaged areas on the data storage device.**

#### If I have a gddrescue *mapfile/logfile,* how do I generate a plain list of unreadable LBA's from it?

The mapfile / logfile contains a list of which **bytes** (hexadecimal numbers) of the source drive is damaged.

It may look like this:

```
#      pos        size  status
0x00000000  0x00001000  +
0x00001000  0x00002000  -
0x00003000  0x0000A000  +
```

0x00001000 bytes are 2048 bytes.
In this example, LBA 2 and 3 are unreadable. LBA 1, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 and 14 are readable.

[From the **manual**:](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html)

> **Character   Meaning** 
>   '?'   copying non-tried blocks
>   '*'    trimming non-trimmed blocks
>   '/'     scraping non-scraped blocks
>   '-'     retrying bad sectors
>   'F'     filling specified blocks
>   'G'     generating approximate mapfile
>   '+'     finished

How can the information in that logfile be used to generate a list of unreadable LBA's?

The *badblocks* command finds 0 bad blocks from a loop device created from that image file. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459154/list-bad-blocks-and-affected-files

It would be good as well if the loop device could simulate unreadability in areas on the HDD listed in the mapfile/logfile generated by gddrescue.

Comment: Somebody downvoted this question without explanation. Excuse me, but if haters are not able to explain the reason for their downvote, their vote should be considered invalid.

Comment: I clarified the question now and consider it as suitable for being re-opened.

Comment: Here is something called *`gddrescuelog`*. I will take a better look at it: http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Generate-mode.

Answer (score 0):

**`gddrescuelog`** is dedicated to that purpose.
https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-ddrescuelog/

The -c option or  --create-mapfile option allows you to create a mapfile, as long as you can provide the correct --block-size or -b, which is usually **512** on flash drives and hard drives and **2048** on optical discs.

The -l, --list-blocks option allows to do the same in reverse, with a given --block-size, generating lists of unreadable LBA's. The mapfile just is a list of hexadecimally listed bytes readable and non-readable. You can output it into >>a_file.list.txt as well.

Manual `man ddrescuelog`: https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-ddrescuelog/ .