# Generate gddrescue log file from badblocks list?

Tags: ddrescue, badblocks

I have a list of *`badblocks`*.

How do I generate a gddrescue mapfile/logfile from it?

Assuming that the sector size is known.

This is the reverse way of *[Generating dead LBA list from gddrescue mapfile/logfile?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476535/generating-dead-lba-list-from-gddrescue-mapfile-logfile)* .

Comment: `ddrescuelog` .